# Bash script to find lines belonging to each other

Tags: bash, grep

I have a log file containing such output:

```
  [mvn] Running com.mypackage.MyTest
   ...
  [mvn] Tests run: 12, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 104.648 sec
  [mvn] Running com.mypackage.MyNotExecutedTest
   ...
  [mvn] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.525 sec
  [mvn] Running com.mypackage.AnotherNotExecutedTest
   ...
  [mvn] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.569 sec
  [mvn] Running com.mypackage.FailedTest
   ...
  [mvn] Tests run: 5, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 22.357 sec
   ...
```

whereas there can be any arbitrary number of lines where "..." is (e.g. stack trace, some debug output). What I want to achieve is a list of tests which hasn't been executed:

```
  com.mypackage.MyNotExecutedTest
  com.mypackage.AnotherNotExecutedTest
```

So my approach was to grep for pattern "Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed" but then I would somehow need a smart way to find out what Test belongs the grep pattern.
Any good/elegant solutions here? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write an `awk` script which stores the latest  `Running` line, then prints the stored line if it sees `Tests run: 0`.

```
awk '/\[mvn\] Running /{ t=$3 }
  /\[mvn\] Tests run: 0/ { print t }'  logfile
```

Edit: I took out the line beginning anchors, in order to correctly cope with indented input.

Comment: I think there is a backslash missing at the second \[mvn\], but nevertheless this command doesn't print out anything if I run it agains my log file?

Comment: Oh, I have assumed the `[mvn]` labels are flush left, but upon closer examination, they seem to be indented. See my edit.

Comment: Actually `]` doesn't strictly need to be backslash-escaped, but at least I ought to be consistent (-:

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do it with a combination of `grep` and `awk`:

```
grep -A1 "Tests run: 0" | awk '/Running {print $NF}'
```

Comment: My understanding is that you need the preceding header line, which may be multiple lines away. You could do `egrep 'Running|Tests run:' | fgrep -B1 'Tests run: 0'`

Comment: thanks a lot tripleee, I even like this solution a little more than your first one :-)

Comment: +1 Hesitant upvote, mainly because this deserves to have at least as many votes as the wicked, wicked `pcregrep` solution /-:

Answer (score 1):

i would do this with several grep commands and an awk, all piped together.  i'll walk you through my logic:

1) use `pcregrep` instead of grep to match a multi-line pattern beginning with "Running" and ending with "Tests run: 0" as follows:

**command:**

```
pcregrep -M "Running(\n|.)*?Tests run: 0" file.txt
```

(note the use of the `-M` argument to allow multi-line matches and the `?` after the asterisk to make it non-greedy)

**output:**

```
[mvn] Running com.mypackage.MyTest
...
[mvn] Tests run: 12, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 104.648 sec
[mvn] Running com.mypackage.MyNotExecutedTest
...
[mvn] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.525 sec
[mvn] Running com.mypackage.AnotherNotExecutedTest
...
[mvn] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.569 sec
```

2) as you can see, this unfortunately matched some unwanted items also, so i'd use pcregrep again to remove the offending entries as follows:

**command:**

```
pcregrep -M "Running(\n|.)*?Tests run: 0" file.txt | \
pcregrep -Mv "Running(\n|.)*?Tests run: [^0]"
```

(note the use of the `-v` argument and the `[^0]` character class in the second pcregrep command to eliminate only processes which ran a non-zero number of tests)

**output:**

```
[mvn] Running com.mypackage.MyNotExecutedTest
...
[mvn] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.525 sec
[mvn] Running com.mypackage.AnotherNotExecutedTest
...
[mvn] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.569 sec
```

3) then i'd grep out just the lines containing "Running":

**command:**

```
pcregrep -M "Running(\n|.)*?Tests run: 0" file.txt | \
pcregrep -Mv "Running(\n|.)*?Tests run: [^0]" | \
grep -i running
```

**output:**

```
[mvn] Running com.mypackage.MyNotExecutedTest
[mvn] Running com.mypackage.AnotherNotExecutedTest
```

4) and finally use awk to print only the variable i'm interested in seeing (the process name, which by your example seems to always be the third "word" in the row):

**final command:**

```
pcregrep -M "Running(\n|.)*?Tests run: 0" file.txt | \
pcregrep -Mv "Running(\n|.)*?Tests run: [^0]" | \
grep -i running | \
awk '{print $3};'
```

**final output:**

```
com.mypackage.MyNotExecutedTest
com.mypackage.AnotherNotExecutedTest
```

hth!